# Asp.Net Core MVC middleware returns 404 instead of 401 even with AuthorizeFilter

Tags: authentication, asp.net-core

I have a very simple web api application that is configured like that:

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
{
    app.UseAuthentication();
    app.UseMvc();
}
```

Services has MVC registration like that:

```
_services
    .AddMvc(config =>
    {
        var policy = new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder()
            .RequireAuthenticatedUser()
            .Build();
        config.Filters.Add(new AuthorizeFilter(policy));
    })
```

There is no default route registered for root, so when I do a request to root of the application, I get 404. What I was expecting to get is 401 though as I thought that absolutely all requests should require authorization.

I have not figured a way to achieve that, and not even sure this is correct semantically, but there is no open endpoints in my API and I would like to just return 401 if there is no authentication for any route.

Comment: You're adding an MVC filter to run during the MVC processing pipeline, but there's no pipeline to run when there's no matching action. So `UseMvc` passes the request onto the next middleware but of course there isn't one and that's why you get a 404.

Comment: One solution would be a terminal middleware after `UseMvc` that just returns a 401.

Comment: Thanks for explanation, I already suspected that much actually, but was not sure what is the best way of fixing it.

Comment: You're welcome. I don't know that's the _best_ way of fixing it but it's likely the _simplest_. :)

Comment: I am also not sure if it is semantically correct to do that, or it's fine to return 404

Comment: I don't think it's common to return a 401 in that case, but that doesn't mean it's wrong. I guess it depends on the consumers of your API. If you say 401, are they going to be confused as to why you don't accept their credentials, for example? A 404 is more explicit without really giving anything away. In fact sometimes I see a 403 turn into a 404 to hide things from unauthorised users (e.g. a private GitHub repo).

Answer (score 0):

ASP.NET uses 401 internally, you will always get 404, you can handle it by using

`AddAuthentification()` Extension in your Service collector

```
   services.AddAuthentication(options =>
        {
            options.DefaultScheme = "Cookies";
        }).AddCookie("Cookies",
          (options) =>
          {
              options.AccessDeniedPath = "..your access denied page route..";
              options.LoginPath ="..your login route.."
          })
```

Comment: I am sorry, I did not mention that, I do use services with Authentication already

Comment: You can use a middleware to handle the error in your application builder
your application like this
            `app.UseStatusCodePagesWithRedirects("~/Error/{0}");`
and Error is your controller name for example. and the {0} will be replaced by the status code,
your action will be like this
     `[HttpGet]
        [Route("{id}")]
        public IActionResult Get(int id)
        {
            Response.StatusCode = id;          
            return View();
        }`