# Web Api returns 404 instead 401 status code

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I have this web api project in NET 6. In this project, I have a authentication controller and I have an endpoint which authenticate based on username and password.

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
[ApiController]
public class AuthenticationController : ControllerBase
{
    private readonly UserManager<ApplicationUser> _userManager;
    private readonly SignInManager<ApplicationUser> _signInManager;
    private readonly IdbContext _dbContext;

    public AuthenticationController(UserManager<ApplicationUser> userManager, SignInManager<ApplicationUser> signInManager, IdbContext _dbContext)
    {
        _userManager = userManager;
        _signInManager = signInManager;
        _dbContext = dbContext;
    }

    [AllowAnonymous]
    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<IActionResult> PasswordSignInAsync([FromBody] LoginRequest loginRequest)
    {         
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            var result = await _signInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(loginRequest.Username, loginRequest.Password, isPersistent: false, lockoutOnFailure: false);
            if (result.Succeeded)
            {
                var armsUser = _dbContext.Users
                    .FirstOrDefault(u => u.Email == loginRequest.Username);

                if (armsUser == null) {
                    await _signInManager.SignOutAsync();
                    return BadRequest();
                }

                ApplicationUser user = await _userManager.FindByEmailAsync(loginRequest.Username);

                if (user == null)
                {
                    return NotFound($"Unable to load user with username '{loginRequest.Username}'.");
                }

                user.LastSignInDate = DateTime.Now;

                await _userManager.UpdateAsync(user);

                await _signInManager.RefreshSignInAsync(user);

                return Ok("Authenticated!");
            }
            await _signInManager.SignOutAsync();
            return BadRequest("Invalid username or password.");
        }
        return BadRequest(ModelState);
    }
}
```

and this is the protected resources.

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
[ApiController]
public class MarketingEventController : ControllerBase
{        
    private readonly IMediator _mediator;

    /// <summary>
    /// 
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="mediator"></param>
    public MarketingEventController(IMediator mediator)
    {     
        _mediator = mediator;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// 
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns></returns>
    [HttpGet]
    [ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status200OK)]
    [ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status404NotFound)]
    [ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status500InternalServerError)]
    public async Task<ActionResult> GetLatest()
    {
        try
        {
            var query = new GetLatestQuery();
            var result = await _mediator.Send(query);
            return Ok(result);

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return Problem(ex.Message);
        }
    }
}
```

and some related code in `program.cs`

```
...

app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();


app.MapControllers().RequireAuthorization();
```

If I am authenticated, I get 200 status code as expected. But If I am not authentication and  call /api/MarketingEvent, why I get 404 status code instead of 401 status code? Even if I decorate the marketing controller with `[Authorize]`, it still behaves the same.

[image]

[image]

Comment: It may be a middleware magic, plz try 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58608536/asp-net-core-mvc-middleware-returns-404-instead-of-401-even-with-authorizefilter

Comment: Could you please show how you configure Authentitication and Authorization, i.e. AddAuthentication and AddAuthorization calls in your Startup?
Also, `RequireAuthorization` registers a convention to apply `[Authorize]` to all controllers so doing it manually should lead to no difference.
Additionally, I would like to inquire regarding framework - you mention .NET 6 and tag is ASP.NET. I presume this relates to ASP.NET Core, not ASP.NET 4.

Comment: Have you checked this question here? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69169310/asp-net-core-5-web-api-returns-404-code-instead-of-401-when-the-user-is-unauthen

Answer (score 0):

`DefaultChallengeScheme` may redirecting to a page that does not exist,  which could cause the 404.

Try setting the default challenge to the Jwt schema which returns not authorized.

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddAuthentication(options =>
    {
       options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = IdentityServerAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
       options.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    })
    .AddIdentityServerAuthentication(options =>
    {
      options.Authority = "http://localhost:60415";
      options.ApiName = "mCareApi";
      options.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
    });
}
```

Comment: I also think that something is wrong with authentication. There's probably an internal redirect to a login page that does not exist. In some older project I'm using https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.authentication.cookies.cookieauthenticationoptions.loginpath?view=aspnetcore-6.0#microsoft-aspnetcore-authentication-cookies-cookieauthenticationoptions-loginpath to specify the path. So maybe the redirect to the login page or an error page leads to a 404

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how have you registered your swagger service, but try to use something like that:

```
services.AddAuthentication(options =>
            {
                options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
                options.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            })
```

Also, Decorate your endpoint with the following attribute

```
[ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status401Unauthorized)]
```

and also, if you want to avoid making this to all your action methods, you have 2 options:

1. you can create a base controller and decorate it with that attribute. Then, make all your controllers inherit from that base controller.
2. you can add a global filter in your program.cs. something like that

```
services.AddMvc(options =>
{
    options.Filters.Add(new Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ProducesResponseTypeAttribute(typeof(ApiError), 400));
    options.Filters.Add(new Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ProducesResponseTypeAttribute(typeof(ApiError), 401));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

In each **GET api/MarketingEvent/** request ASP.NET Core Routing will try to match incoming request with an Action method in your controller. In this case you haven't specified any Action method so it will look for the default Action method which is **Index**. This is why it is returning 404 Not Found.

I assume you want to call **GetLatest** action method so you need to decorate **GetLatest** action method with an empty **[Route("")]** attribute. Your method will look like this:

```
/// <summary>
/// 
/// </summary>
/// <returns></returns>
[HttpGet]
[Route("")]
[ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status200OK)]
[ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status404NotFound)]
[ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status500InternalServerError)]
public async Task<ActionResult> GetLatest()
{
    try
    {
        var query = new GetLatestQuery();
        var result = await _mediator.Send(query);
        return Ok(result);

    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        return Problem(ex.Message);
    }
}
```

Comment: ``If I am authenticated, I get 200 status code as expected. `` read this line..